# use Ev and Road Runner together?

Tags: php, periodic-task, roadrunner

app_example.php

trying to combine an example of RR app and Ev together.
trying to use Ev to update a global variable,
which is used in HTTP response.

Ev::run(Ev::RUN_NOWAIT);
does not seem to have any effect.

Ev::run();
works. but Ev is done before the http request is handled.
Would like to have the Ev executed periodically while http request is being handled,
at the same time.

```
use Spiral\RoadRunner;
use Nyholm\Psr7;

include "vendor/autoload.php";

$worker = RoadRunner\Worker::create();
$psrFactory = new Psr7\Factory\Psr17Factory();

$psr7 = new RoadRunner\Http\PSR7Worker($worker, $psrFactory, $psrFactory, $psrFactory);

$global_variable = 0;

**$w = new EvTimer(2, 1, function ($w) {
    global $global_variable;
    $global_variable++;
    echo "is called every second, is launched after 2 seconds\n";
    echo "iteration = ", Ev::iteration(), PHP_EOL;
    // Stop the watcher after 5 iterations
    Ev::iteration() == 5 and $w->stop();
    // Stop the watcher if further calls cause more than 10 iterations
    Ev::iteration() >= 10 and $w->stop();
});
Ev::run(Ev::RUN_NOWAIT);
# Ev::run();**

while (true) {
    try {
        $request = $psr7->waitRequest();

        if (!($request instanceof \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface)) { // Termination request received
            break;
        }
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        $psr7->respond(new Psr7\Response(400)); // Bad Request
        continue;
    }

    try {
        // Application code logic
        $psr7->respond(new Psr7\Response(200, [], 'Hello RoadRunner!' . $global_variable));
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        $psr7->respond(new Psr7\Response(500, [], 'Something Went Wrong!'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems ReactPHP gives me what I need!

Wish I had started with ReactPHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

use React\EventLoop\Loop;

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$http = new React\Http\HttpServer(function (Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface $request) {
    return React\Http\Message\Response::plaintext(
        "Hello World!\n"
    );
});

$socket = new React\Socket\SocketServer('127.0.0.1:8080');
$http->listen($socket);

echo "Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8080" . PHP_EOL;


Loop::addPeriodicTimer(5, function () {
    $memory = memory_get_usage() / 1024;
    $formatted = number_format($memory, 3).'K';
    echo "Current memory usage: {$formatted}\n";
    # here is my own little logic to get data from db
    # to update global variables
});
```